# Why is it advantageous to return by reference?

Tags: c++, return-by-reference

I know that the rule of thumb is that we return by reference iff the returned variable exists in the caller.
Say we have a function:

```
int& f(int& a){ return a; }
```

Now, in the caller, I can call in 2 ways:

```
int a = 5;
int b1 = f(a); // 1
int& b2 = f(a); // 2
```

The difference is that change in b1 or a in the caller, doesn't effect one another, but changes in b2 or a in caller effects one another.

That means, what a was referring to int the callee is copied to b2, whereas, it seems like only the value a was referring to in the callee was copied to b1 because of the above statement.

Then what is the advantage of returning by referrence like 1st case if it copies as well.
Example where statements like 1 are seen is copy assignment operator which returns by reference for chaining of assignments:
eg: obj1 = obj2 = obj3;

Am I missing something here?

Comment: imho the semantic difference is more important than any performance concerns. If `f` should return a copy then it should return a copy, if it should return a reference then a reference. Either is wrong when the other is needed

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not quite get your point.

Comment: Maybe relevant: You return by reference in both cases above. It's only that you in `b1` make a copy and in `b2` you keep the reference.

Comment: And you can always have move semantic and copy elision to eliminate the cost. The reference will actually cost you performance in the above cases.

Comment: Yes, I know that it returns by reference in both cases. But 1 still gets a copy and 2 gets a refrence.

Comment: Your question could also be written as "Why is it disadvantageous to make copies of variables?"  I am also not sure that your "rule of thumb" is a commonly-followed rule.  _"iff the returned variable exists"_ should not be the determining factor as to whether the return type should be a reference.

Comment: "what is the advantage of" is not a great way to phrase your question.  We can tell you objectively how the language works.  And possibly tell you a bit about why certain features of the language exist.  As for the unqualified general benefits of choosing a particular valid approach over another, we're getting well into opinionated territory.  All I can say is you can do `f(foo) = 5` to assign `foo = 5` but now you have a mechanism for at least "hooking" that assignment, or potentially referencing something else.  Your toy example is too minimal to provide any concrete value.

Comment: Why is it disadvantageous to use a hammer to drive in a screw?  Why is it disadvantageous to use a screwdriver to pound in a nail?

Comment: @DrewDormann when do we return by value then?

Comment: @SumukhBhat is that the question you are asking here?  If so, that is certainly a clearer question than "Am I missing something?"

Comment: @SumukhBhat *what is the advantage of returning by referrence* -- What if you want the actual object you are working on, instead of a copy?  `std::vector<int> getVector() { return myVect; }` will not work.  `std::vector<int>& getVector() { return myVect; }` will work.  There have been many program bugs (and threads started here) where the OP did the former, but meant to do the latter.

Comment: Returning a reference means that any code review is going to take twice as long as we now have to carefully review the lifetime of what is being returned.

Comment: got it, thanks for all your answers/inputs. I was under an impression that since pass by reference is better than pass by value for large objects, there must be something related to return by reference as well. Clearly I was thinking wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly your argument is moot.

Along the same line of reasoning you could argue that there is no advantage of using a reference in general, because it can be used to make a copy:

```
int x = 42; 
int& ref = x;
int y = ref;    // makes a copy
```

However, just because you **can** use a reference to make a copy does not decrease usability of a reference:

```
ref = 24;  // does modify x
```

In your example:

> ```
> int a = 5;
> int b1 = f(a); // 1
> int& b2 = f(a); // 2
> ```

It has almost nothing to do with `f` that the caller decided to make a copy in `// 1`. Of course you can use a reference to make a copy. But you cannot use a copy to modify `a`:

```
  f(a) = 42;   // modifies a
```

This only works as inteded (modify `a`) when `f` returns a reference.

As an analogy you could ask: Whats the advantage of using an airplane? Airplanes can drive on the ground just like cars can do ;)